# copying cookies between WKWebView and HTTPCookieStorage - not finding 302 cookies

Tags: ios, cookies, ios9, wkwebview, ios10

We are copying cookies from WKWebView to HTTPCookitStorage.shared to be used by URLSession tasks.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

    if let response = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse {

        var headers = [String : String]()
        for (header, value) in response.allHeaderFields {
            headers[(header as? String)!] = value as? String
        }
        let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headers, for: response.url!)
        for cookie: HTTPCookie in cookies {
            print(cookie)
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
        }
    }

    decisionHandler(.allow)

}
```

That captures most cookies, but not if there was a 302 redirect happening in the WKWebView.  Is there a delegate method or some other technique that I can do to capture the cookies from a response that has a 302 response code?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue

Comment: No.  We used UIWebView for the login, captured the cookies.  Used a WKUserScript to copy the cookies into the WKWebView.

Comment: from what I've seen there is no WKNavigationDelegate method that permits access to response headers and so on. Hoping that iOS 11 will solve some of these limitations.

Comment: ps. question does look like a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659341/wkwebview-cant-carry-cookie-for-302-redirect and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576468/when-redirect-with-code-302-wkwebview-cannot-set-cookie

Comment: @MaxMacLeod Those questions are duplicates of this post

Comment: yes you're right. Unfortunately I can't close them as there's no upvoted or accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PWKWebView](https://github.com/luowenxing/PWKWebView/) to replace your original `WKWebView`.

Comment: but its not sending the Cookies shared during redirects.